# Getting Error while executing in cmd

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdQaC.jpg)

Working on MEAN App but i got struck by this error since 6 hours can anyone help me

12 error Windows_NT 6.1.7601
13 error argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Users\NARAYANAMMA\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "start"
14 error node v6.0.0
15 error npm  v2.12.1
16 error code ELIFECYCLE
17 error contactlistapp@1.0.0 start: `node server.js`
17 error Exit status 1
18 error Failed at the contactlistapp@1.0.0 start script 'node server.js'.
18 error This is most likely a problem with the contactlistapp package,
18 error not with npm itself.
18 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
18 error     node server.js
18 error You can get their info via:
18 error     npm owner ls contactlistapp
18 error There is likely additional logging output above.
19 verbose exit [ 1, true ]

Comment: Show people what have you done so far?

Comment: Looks like moviestub package used from npm is not available or not working.

Comment: https://github.com/msivarohith/movieStub

Comment: I pushed my code in to github can u check on that  @NikiMihaylov